# Avoiding boilerplate when error handling in multiple components

Tags: angular

I'm trying to avoid boilerplate error handling when displaying components that get data from a service.

Currently, the container component loads the data from the service and shares this data with each sub-component through an `Input()` attribute 'results'. When the service returned an error, it will set another `Input()` attribute 'error'.

The template will display data if there's data, error if there's an error, or a loading spinner if neither.

**container.component.html**

```html
<app-sub-component-1 [result]="this.data1" [error]="this.error1">
<app-sub-component-2 [result]="this.data2" [error]="this.error2">
```

**container.component.ts**

```js
this.service.getData.subscribe(data => {
   this.data1 = data;
},
error => {
this.error1 = error;
});
this.service.getOtherData.subscribe(data => {
   this.data2 = data;
},
error => {
this.error2 = error;
});
...
```

This is of course horrible code repetition, especially since there are many components, but I don't know the Angular way to do this. Note that it is important that each error associated with the subcomponent must be displayed inside this component.

Is there a way I can avoid this boilerplate, e.g. by inheriting a global error component? Should I stop sharing data via `Input()` attributes and rather give every service its own code?

Comment: *it is important that each error associated with the subcomponent must be displayed inside this component* well you either have to have this happen in the component or not. If this is a requirement I don't see how you can centralise this.

Comment: *(can I) inheriting a global error component* erm, yes..if you want? The question here really isn't very clear.

Comment: I'm just looking for a best practice here. Seems like I'm doing something wrong writing so much boilerplate.